# Can I use .NET 8 Bearer Token Authentication Handler to create Reference tokens rather than a self contained JWT style token?

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, access-token, .net-8.0

I'm currently using IdentityServer4 v3.1.1 with reference tokens but I want to move away from IdentityServer altogether if possible for a number of reasons including their new licensing policy and the fact that it's just total overkill for my needs.

I do however like reference tokens as opposed to JWT style tokens due to the fact that a) they contain no real data and b) they can be revoked, something that is critical to our application.
I also like the simplicity of the new .NET 8 Bearer Token Authentication Handler.

Is there anyway I can use the new authentication stuff in .NET 8 whilst also sticking with reference tokens?

Comment: I didn't think the tokens issued by the BearerToken handler will be acceptable in APIs (using JwtBearer).  I did blog about the handler here https://nestenius.se/2023/08/29/bearertoken-the-new-authentication-handler-in-net-8/

The bearer token handler is mearly for SPA applications  with one single backend service.

Answer (score 1):

The new bearer token handler in .NET can only issue one set of tokens, as shown in the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f533c51cd99901e8f3ed5004bd9ce7d824ea8e9a/src/Security/Authentication/BearerToken/src/BearerTokenHandler.cs#L64).

The tokens are not JWT tokens, so you can't ues them to talk to any APIs and I did blog about what the token contains in my blog post [here](https://nestenius.se/2023/08/29/bearertoken-the-new-authentication-handler-in-net-8/) and the tokens are meant to be used by mainly by SPA applications against ASP.NET Identity.

So, this handler is not relevant for OpenID-Connect or JWTBearer APIs.